# Adding buttons to PDF documents in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, pdf

I'm writing an iPad app where the user will open PDF documents.
I want to substitute some unique texts with clickable buttons.

ie. if there is a text: "Please click a button" I want to put a button instead (or over) the word "button".

What is the right way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is not a straight forward solution to it. What you need to do is following :
1) Search for text 'button'. PDF document text extraction needs to happen before this. Performace depends on how you do this. Some PDF parsers create a marker and while rendering the PDF it indexes the text data of PDF. So searching becomes faster. There can be many more approaches :)
2) Get the bounding box coordinates of the text in screen space.
2) Now draw a platform widget on this coordinate.